# C - program is terminated (fork() and exec())

Tags: c, linux

I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char    *program;
    char     stringa[1000] = "";
    int num = 123;
    char snum[5];

    program = argv[1];

    sprintf(stringa, "./%s", program);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0 ) {
        perror("fork failed."); 
        exit(1); }

    else if (pid == 0) {
        char* args[] = {stringa, NULL};
        execv(args[0], args);
    }

    else {
        char procmon_str[] = "./procmon ";
        num = pid;
        sprintf(snum, "%d",num);
        printf("PID of child is %s", snum);

        char* args2[] = {procmon_str, snum, NULL};
        execv(args2[0], args2);

        sleep(20);
        kill(num, SIGTERM);

        sleep(2);
        int parent_pid = getpid(); 
        printf("PID of parent is %d", parent_pid);
        kill(parent_pid, SIGTERM);

    }

    wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to call with program with 1 command line argument which is a name of another compiled C program in the same folder.
I want to execute that program from within the C code (hence the use of `fork()`), and at the same time i want to launch another program from within the `parent` part of the `fork()`.

The part that is in the `child` part of `fork()` works perfectly, but when i run it through the shell it says `Terminated` right after and does not execute the code in the `parent` part of the `fork()`.

Why is that?

Comment: You're not waiting for the child to finish with `wait()`. The space at the end of `./procmon` prevents finding the program to run.

Comment: `execv()` doesn't normally return, because it replaces the current process with the program you ask it to run. If it returns, it means it got an error, so you should print the error message with `perror()`.

Comment: If the program works correctly, all the stuff you have after `execv` in the parent will never execute. You should put it first.

Comment: I'm confused - should i wait for the child to finish? should i run first the parent's part of the `execv`?

Comment: I don't understand why you go through all the trouble with snum and sprintf when you can just use %d in printf? like: printf("PID of child is %d", pid);

Comment: You wrote "then after it is done I want to launch another program". Doesn't that mean you want to wait for it to finish?

Comment: Yes i do, what should i put there then? `wait` for how long? I'm relatively new to C, sorry..

Comment: Also you define snum as a char[5], pid can be a number with more than 4 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your program call `fork()`. Now the execution of the parent process and the child process proceeds in parallel.
2. The child:

   - Builds the argument array `args[]`.
   - Calls `execv()` and is replaced by the program supplied as argument.
3. The parent, in parallel with the child:

   - Builds the argument array `args2[]`.
   - Calls `execv()` and is replaced by `./procmon`.

The code from `sleep(20)` onwards in not reached unless the `execv()` fails (which you did not check for).

Read the manual page for `fork()` again, and redo the logic of the program.

Comment: Don't wrap the code for the parent in an `else { ... }` -- it is useless. In the code for the parent _first_ wait for the child to finish, and only _afterwards_ call `execv()`.

Comment: I think it wasn't clear from my question (sorry) but i do need to make sure both the child and parent parts run at the same time. That is because the process that runs in the parent part, uses the `pid` of the process run by the child part.

Comment: Your initial question specifically said that you want to run a program _after_ the child is done. If you want `./procmon` to run in parallel with the child then your code is workable. Just add error checking and remember that a successful `execv()` does not return.

Comment: What am i supposed to do if it doesn't return? Since in the parent part, i need to execute a process and then execute more code (like the `sleep` and `kill` parts).
Should i fork twice?

Comment: Alright, i will do that, appreciate your help! If anyone has another suggestion/answer please feel free to comment.